# Trying to list all applications installed on 64 bit machine

Tags: vbscript, registry, 32bit-64bit, wmic

I've been asked to gather information from our users of what software they have installed on their machines.  I found some vb code [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/UNVsnFiKNEA/GhHalTt4q2EJ) that (mostly) works for me - it goes through and checks out the uninstall part of the registry.

The results I get from the vb contain different entries than what I get when I list the installed software via wmic (which only lists stuff that uses the windows installer).

My problem is that I notice that the vb code is only getting 64bit applications, and I need both 64 and 32-bit.

Given that the code I'm using is searching "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" and finding 64 bit stuff, is there somewhere else I can point it to find 32 bit stuff?

Thanks for any assistance,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK people, Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, but I found my answer - 
32 bit installed software can be found in

```
Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else.